# Windows.Form won't show

Tags: c#, winforms

All I want to do is display a blank windows form. I am using Visual Studio and was following this tutorial 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153258(v=vs.85).aspx
However, when I ran it, nothing happened. A blank window did not open.
I simplified the code to see what the problem was, so here is my code:

```
public partial class CreateDevice : Form
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CreateDevice frm = new CreateDevice();
        frm.Show();
    }
    public CreateDevice()
    {
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
        this.Text = "D3D Tutorial 01: CreateDevice";
    }
}
```

Except when run, nothing happens.
I appreciate any advice.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I would suggest creating a new Windows Forms Application project & checking the automatically generated code.

Comment: You need to call `frm.ShowDialog()` instead of `frm.Show()`. `Show` opens the form as non-modal and returns immediatly, so your `Main` method continues, returns and the process is terminated. So the window disappears immediatly. `ShowDialog` opens a modal window that takes control, and `Main` will wait until the window is closed and `ShowDialog` returns.

Comment: You missed the while-loop from the tutorial you are following.

Answer (score 4):

**Edited**There were actually several things wrong with your code. First, you need a `Program` class with a static `Main` method--this is where the computer enters your program and starts running things, without it the computer won't do a thing. You need a partial class--not merely a method--inheriting from `Form`. And finally, inside the `Program.Main` method you need `Application.Run` which runs an application context (if you give it a `Form` type argument it creates the context automatically).  You need to call `Application.Run` instead of `show`:

```
static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        CreateDevice frm = new CreateDevice();
        Application.Run(frm);
    }

}
public partial class CreateDevice : Form
{
    public CreateDevice()
    {
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
        this.Text = "D3D Tutorial 01: CreateDevice";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe im missing something here but doesnt he NOT call the Main method at all and the constructor doesn't show the form?

Comment: @joko: Yeah you're right. I misread his code and quickly modified it, but in fact he didn't have `Program` at all so no wonder it didn't work. Just made some edits.